# RS485 (MAX489) biasing

Tags: rs485, biasing, modbus

I am making an RS485 client device. The prototype is able to transmit and receive from a Modbus server successfully, using 2-wire (half duplex) mode. Full duplex operation is planned, but I haven't tried it yet.

Does the [MAX489](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf) require any pull up/down biasing resistors? I can find no mention in their docs about this, nor specifics about 'fail safe' biasing.

Actually, it does sort of mention there is a pull-up for an open network condition. Does this suffice, or is a pull-down also needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet says on the first page:

> The receiver input has a fail-safe feature that guarantees a logic-high output if the input is open circuit.

(Please note that "input" means both differential input pins.)

Table 2 shows the same. So you don't need the biasing resistor for this receiver if you do not have termination resistors. If any other receivers on the bus do not have this feature, or if you have termination resistors (which force a zero differential voltage if no transmitter is driving the bus), the bus still needs biasing.

There are receivers that guarantee a high level when the differential voltage is zero; those would not need biasing in any case. The MAX489 is not one of those.

On a receiver without fail-safe feature, you would use *two* resistors: a pull-up resistor to force the *non-inverting* input high, and a pull-down resistor to force the *inverting* input down. Due to the *differential* receiver, this would be interpreted as a high level; a differential receiver would not work with a single pull resistor, because the other input would be floating, or still at the same level.

If the fail-safe feature is implemented with resistors, then the specified behaviour would imply that there are two resistors, one on each pin. But the datasheet does not mention any pull-up/-down resistors; how the fail-safe feature is actually implemented does not matter to you.

Comment: So the MAX family has full fail-safe provisions? If just the pull-up, is that sufficient?

Comment: I am having some odd behavior. With just the master device, no external resistances added, I get Vab = 270 mV. If I put terminating resistor(s), 150 ohm, in place, Vab drops to a solid zero. That has me baffled.

Comment: On a whim I placed 470 ohm resistors as a pullup on the A pin and pull-down on B. This gave me Vcc on Vab, as expected. I then added 150 ohm terminators to each end of the cable (50 ohm cable) and with no device got about 350 mV as Vab. I then connected a single slave (2 wire) and Vab did not change and communications to the RTU were successful.

Comment: I've clarified my answer. You got a Vab of zero because the transmitter was inactive (no current flows, and no current implies no voltage drop over the termination resistor).

Comment: So, I take that to mean that with Vab = 0 and with no device on the loop, there is no failsafe pullup impedance on the IC? I can't speak for the devices I may encounter, and almost always there will be a termination, so I suppose I should force the biasing and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, the MAX489 has no failsafe for Vab = 0 (neither pull-up/-down resistors nor any other mechanism).

Comment: Great answer, only part it leaves out is the line biasing resistor values? The datasheet shows termination resistors but no line biasing pull up/down. Would be nice if it showed it!

Comment: Are you 100% sure a failsafe transceiver like MAX485 needs line biasing if terminating resistors are used? It doesn't show it in the datasheet. [This TI doc](https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slla545/slla545.pdf) says you need a failsafe transceiver OR line biasing. It doesn't say terminating resistors require line biasing with a failsafe transceiver.

Comment: @NateS There are different levels of fail safe; compare with the MAX3085. And new questions do not belong in comments; ask a new question.

Comment: MAX3085 "guarantees a logic-high receiver output when the receiver inputs are shorted or open, or when they are connected to a terminated transmission line with all drivers disabled" and has a whole section on fail-safe. Maxim seems to call this "true fail-safe". MAX485 "guarantees a logic-high output if the input is open circuit". That is the _only_ thing the datasheet says about it. It's a bummer the MAX485 datasheet doesn't explain it at all.

Comment: @NateS To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @CL Indeed. Also, to add a comment, click `Add comment`. Comments are useful for clarification on an answer, for which a question would be inappropriate. It may have taken me a while but it is clear now. Your help was appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Biasing RS485 networks is a subject that is really not specific to the interface part that you are using. Also keep in mind whilst the interface uses two signalling wires it is essential that you also interconnect devices with an GND wire as well.

You can find all kinds of information online regarding RS485 but there is an [online eBook published by B&B Electronics](http://www.bb-elec.com/Learning-Center/All-White-Papers/Serial/RS-422-and-RS-485-Applications-eBook.aspx) that you may want to take a detailed look through. In it you will find a wealth of information regarding interfacing biasing and terminations. The following picture borrowed from the eBook on page 38 shows the type of basing you would use in a network where terminations are used.

[image]

Comment: The says he's trying to implement a Modbus, which requires 150 Ohm, not 120 Ohm terminations.

Comment: also termination at the top looks like it has wrong impedance: 120||470||470

Comment: @OlinLathrop - Actually the question is a mix of Rs485 and Modbus as written. :-(

Comment: @Jasen - I just showed a picture from the B&B white paper. If you disagee with its content it may be well to take that up with Advantec/B&B.

Comment: I use a B&B USB-485 converter all the time and it is a great device, I love it.

The paper referenced by @MichaelKaras is a great read, although they seem to reverse the A/B +/- usage compared to what I usually see. other good stuff from TI.

I'll be using 650 and 120 as my R values. I work for Schneider, we terminate almost always at 120 despite what the Modbus std. says...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement a Modbus, then the right place to look is in the Modbus spec.

The Modbus spec says that each end of the differential bus *must* be terminated with 150 Ω between the two differential lines.  This means the bus lines look like they're held together with 75 Ω to anything driving the bus.

The Modbus spec also allows for "line polarization".  This is basically putting pullup and pulldown resistors on the line so that it floats to the idle state.  If used, these resistors must be 450 to 650 Ω and should be near the bus master.

Comment: thx for info. As best I can tell is that the 489 has the pullup (value unknown), but I can't find any mention of it having a pulldown on the A.